# Pie Chart Balloon

Tags: javascript, charts, pie-chart, amcharts

I have a difficulty with `Pie Chart Balloon`. I put link to the balloon but when I hover on balloon the balloon keeps blinking.

How to prevent balloon from blinking?

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "status": "Completed",
    "value": 100,
    "color": "#33cc33"
  }, {
    "status": "On-Going",
    "value": 59,
    "color": "#1a53ff"
  }, {
    "status": "PRE Procurement",
    "value": 36,
    "color": "#ff0066"
  }, {
    "status": "DED Prep",
    "value": 40,
    "color": "#cc66ff"
  }, {
    "status": "Under Prep / Not Yet Started",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#999966"
  }, {
    "status": "Suspended",
    "value": 34,
    "color": "#663300"
  }, {
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }, {
    "status": "No Status Yet",
    "value": 21,
    "color": "#ffff66"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
   "balloon": {
   //"hideBalloonTime": 1000, // 1second
    "disableMouseEvents": false, // allow click
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "valueField": "value",
  "titleField": "status",
  "colorField": "color",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)<br><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#completed'>View Data</a></span>",
  "angle": 50,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post a working code snippet of your source code? You can use codepen/jsfiddle/plunker or some other similar service

Comment: @VicJordan sir i already posted the code on codepen, thank you

Comment: Maybe that's a good thing. Pie charts are rarely the best chart to for informative data visualisation. Please try other charts instead, like horizontal bar charts. They are much better to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Balloons are not the best choice for links in a pie chart since the flicker occurs once you move the cursor off the slice onto the balloon, which will disappear before you can click on it. There is no setting to disable this behavior. If you *need* the link in the balloon, set [`hideBalloonTime`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#hideBalloonTime) in the **top level** of the chart config to a large enough number (your commented code has this set as a balloon-object level config, which is incorrect). Note that the "flicker" will still occur if the user hovers over the balloon for too long.

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "hideBalloonTime": 2000, //hideBalloonTime is set here. Value in milliseconds
  "dataProvider": [ {
    "status": "Completed",
    "value": 100,
    "color": "#33cc33"
  }, {
    "status": "On-Going",
    "value": 59,
    "color": "#1a53ff"
  }, {
    "status": "PRE Procurement",
    "value": 36,
    "color": "#ff0066"
  }, {
    "status": "DED Prep",
    "value": 40,
    "color": "#cc66ff"
  }, {
    "status": "Under Prep / Not Yet Started",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#999966"
  }, {
    "status": "Suspended",
    "value": 34,
    "color": "#663300"
  }, {
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }, {
    "status": "No Status Yet",
    "value": 21,
    "color": "#ffff66"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
   "balloon": {
   //"hideBalloonTime": 1000, // does NOT go here
    "disableMouseEvents": false, // allow click
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "valueField": "value",
  "titleField": "status",
  "colorField": "color",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)<br><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#completed'>View Data</a></span>",
  "angle": 50,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

A better option in this case would be to use CSS to make the slice appear to be clickable using [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmChart#addClassNames) and use the [`clickSlice`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmPieChart#clickSlice) event to trigger your link (or modal, in your case):

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "addClassNames": true, //needed to change cursor for pie slice in CSS
  "dataProvider": [{
    "status": "Completed",
    "value": 100,
    "color": "#33cc33"
  }, {
    "status": "On-Going",
    "value": 59,
    "color": "#1a53ff"
  }, {
    "status": "PRE Procurement",
    "value": 36,
    "color": "#ff0066"
  }, {
    "status": "DED Prep",
    "value": 40,
    "color": "#cc66ff"
  }, {
    "status": "Under Prep / Not Yet Started",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#999966"
  }, {
    "status": "Suspended",
    "value": 34,
    "color": "#663300"
  }, {
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }, {
    "status": "No Status Yet",
    "value": 21,
    "color": "#ffff66"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "balloon": {
    //"hideBalloonTime": 1000, // 1second
    "disableMouseEvents": false, // allow click
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "valueField": "value",
  "titleField": "status",
  "colorField": "color",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)<br>Click slice to view data</span>",
  "angle": 50,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "listeners": [{
    "event": "clickSlice",
    "method": function(e) {
      $("#complete").modal('show');
    }
  }]
});

$("#complete").modal({show: false});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

/* change cursor when hovering over slice */
.amcharts-pie-slice {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>

<div class="modal fade" id="complete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added `svg>g>g:last-child { pointer-events: none }` to CSS file and looks it is working fine.

Check the below working code:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "pie",
  "theme": "light",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "status": "Completed",
    "value": 100,
    "color": "#33cc33"
  }, {
    "status": "On-Going",
    "value": 59,
    "color": "#1a53ff"
  }, {
    "status": "PRE Procurement",
    "value": 36,
    "color": "#ff0066"
  }, {
    "status": "DED Prep",
    "value": 40,
    "color": "#cc66ff"
  }, {
    "status": "Under Prep / Not Yet Started",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#999966"
  }, {
    "status": "Suspended",
    "value": 34,
    "color": "#663300"
  }, {
    "status": "Cancelled",
    "value": 23,
    "color": "#ff0000"
  }, {
    "status": "No Status Yet",
    "value": 21,
    "color": "#ffff66"
  }],
  "startDuration": 1,
  "balloon": {
    //"hideBalloonTime": 1000, // 1second
    "disableMouseEvents": false, // allow click
    "fixedPosition": true
  },
  "valueField": "value",
  "titleField": "status",
  "colorField": "color",
  "outlineAlpha": 0.4,
  "depth3D": 30,
  "balloonText": "<b>[[title]]</b><br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)<br><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#completed'>View Data</a></span>",
  "angle": 50,
  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}

svg>g>g:last-child {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/pie.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: thank you but it still blinking, i'm trying to find another solution but i cant find..

Comment: @Darsil but for me it is not blinking. How are you checking it?

Comment: @VicJordan - its not working with code snippet example. just check it with full screen.